# What is the chance of getting a reset bag?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

When you get a punching bag it is randomly decided what bag you will get. What is the chance that it will be a Reset Bag?

Comment: Earn a bag?  Care to be more specific?

Comment: When ever a bag is earned, but I changed it so it is easier to understand what I am asking.

Comment: I can't find any information on the percentage chance of getting one. Some people say they get one first try, and some people say they try for 2 hours and never see one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no known rate, and the exact rate will be unknown until the people who are currently working their way through the games code find it.

Reset bags are fairly uncommon however, if you assume that there is an equal rate of obtaining a bag:

6*3 (stats bags)  + 8 special bags = 26 bag types

That's a 3.4% chance.

---

Source: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Super_Training